# Probability conjunction addition proof

Tags: probability, self-study

I have been tasked with proving the following theorem.

> $$\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A \wedge B) + \mathbb{P}(A \wedge \neg B)$$

This is homework, so only hints are required (and would be greatly appreciated). I am well aware of the axioms of probability.

Comment: I would start with $P(A)$ and try to modify it so that it "contains" $B \cup \bar B$.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram showing the sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Which axioms are you allowed to use? The very basic ones or some results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(\{ A \cap B \} \cup \{ A \cap B^c \}).
$$

Now apply disjoint additivity.